# move folder in windows overwriting the destination folder

Tags: windows

I am trying to move a folder to a location where this folder already exists. So basically I want to overwriting it without prompting yes or no.

Below is the directory structure-

```
C:\TEMP\MOVE_TEST
├───dest
│   └───test_folder
└───test_folder
```

The move command is showing `Access is denied,` while executing below command-

```
c:\>move /y C:\temp\move_test\test_folder C:\temp\move_test\dest
Access is denied.
```

The command `move /y` is overwriting files successfully but in case of folder, it is giving `Access is denied` message.

Comment: The move command with *directory* names just renames the directory and doesn't move any files.  Access denied, the new directory already exists.  You'd have to delete it or rename it first.  Ask questions like this at superuser.com, this is not a programming question.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you please move it to appropriate web?

Answer (score -1):

2 ways:

1. Either you dont have the Administrator rights. If so ask the administrator to grant you rights.
2. You would have opened command prompt only through "cmd" from start menu.
   try opening cmd with ctrl+shift+Enter... that will open cmd in admin mode and then try moving the files...

Comment: I have full administrative rights. Also the command `move /y` is successfully overwriting files BUT NOT folder. I am using `Windows 7`